# NGINX server_name not work 2

Tags: express, nginx

My website always open in path localhost, but my server_name have other domen name. How i can fix it ? 
My configuration

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXm5k.jpg

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  mydomain;

        #charset koi8-r;

        access_log  logs/host.access.log;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3037;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your config to below

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        return 403;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  mydomain;

        #charset koi8-r;

        access_log  logs/host.access.log;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3037;
        }

    }

}
```

First server block is the default server nginx will serve the request from if no virtual host matches. So you need to have 2 blocks in case you only want specific `server_name` to be allowed and rest all to be denied

Answer (score 2):

For testing and accepting doing a "catch-all", you can  use `server_name _`

From: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

> In catch-all server examples the strange name “_” can be seen:

```
server {
    listen       80  default_server;
    server_name  _;
    return       444; 
}
```

Comment: thank . is's working local on VPS , but still i cant connect from my computer . Does this solution work only for the local computer?

Comment: it works for all, just in case you have ipv6 use this `listen [::]:80;
listen 80;` so that you can listen both ipv6 ipv4, also check your firewall from the VPS that allows incoming connections to you port 80

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu you also have to define in `/etc/hosts` your server name for you local ip:
`127.0.0.1 mydomain www.mydomain.com mydomain.com`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

Answer (score 0):

You have to match your custom domain name to your machine's local IP address.
This can be done using the default 127.0.0.1 or by typing the command, "ip addr" in your Ubuntu terminal. this command will list out two IP addresses offered by you machine.
You can match any of the IP addresses to your custom domain in the "/etc/hosts" file.

Answer (score 0):

solution:
add bad urls to "/etc/hosts"
like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qcyx.png)

Comment: This is already mentioned in [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55018346/6045800) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67612213/6045800)